# Full-text search in mongodb in russian

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I'm trying to use full text search in mongodb:

```
> db.collection.insert({"text" : "Первый второй третий"})
> db.collection.insert({"text" : "первый Второй третий"})
> db.collection.insert({"text" : "первый второй Третий"})
> db.collection.ensureIndex({"text" : "text"}, {"default_language" : "russian"})
```

Sentences differ only in letter case.

```
> db.collection.runCommand("text" , {search : "первый"})
{
        "queryDebugString" : "перв||||||",
        "language" : "russian",
        "results" : [
                {
                        "score" : 0.6666666666666666,
                        "obj" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("516acfe2dbfd90a837e09131"),
                                "text" : "первый Второй третий"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "score" : 0.6666666666666666,
                        "obj" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("516acfe8dbfd90a837e09132"),
                                "text" : "первый второй Третий"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "stats" : {
                "nscanned" : 2,
                "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                "n" : 2,
                "nfound" : 2,
                "timeMicros" : 86
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

The result consists only of two entries but it should be three. In English everything is good.

Comment: I think this is because the search isn't case insensitive actually, or rather the index isn't.

Comment: But in documentation it is written that search is case-insensitive (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/). Or is it applicable only for English language?

Comment: @rill could it be English only case-sensitive?

Comment: very bad that text seach doesn't support russian yet..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known limitation of text search as it exists in MongoDB 2.4.  For the purposes of text search, MongoDB will treat the each of the characters "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" (the "uppercase" set in the POSIX locale) the same as its lowercase equivalent, but it will treat other UTF-8 code points as unique.

Full case-folding support for UTF-8 is to come in a future release; see the associated ticket in JIRA at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8423.

Comment: The case-folding support for UTF-8 was released in 3.2 with the version 3 of text indexes.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#case-insensitivity